# How Do I Start a New E-mail Dialogue Box Within Outlook 365 Desktop Application in C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, interop

I am looking for a way to open up a new e-mail dialogue box in Outlook 365 pre-populated with Subject, HTML Contents, Attachments, and Contacts (To, From, etc.). I want to be able to open the dialogue box in code, wait for the user to either click send, or close the window, and detect whether they actually sent the e-mail, or closed the window. I used to be able to do this with the Outlook 2013 Interop, but for the life of me, I cannot seem to find an "Outlook 365 Interop" anywhere to use.

To clarify, I do NOT want to just send the e-mail for them, I want to open the window for them with it being pre-populated, and detect whether or not they chose to send the message in their Outlook Desktop E-mail Client.

Is there an Interop for the Outlook 365 product, and if so, where can I find it? Because I can't find a reference to an Outlook 365 Interop anywhere.

Comment: Are you able to use a browser and the [mailto syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto)? That might be easier.

Comment: Outlook interop is a set of .NET libraries that you have to install. For 2013, you probably need VS 2013/2015 with Office tools installed, not sure if VS 2017/2019 still have those templates.

Comment: @gunr2171 isn't that restricted to the client's default mail program?

Comment: @Taco it is, but I'm hoping that the OP is using this Outlook modification in a _work_ environment where they can control the computer's default mail program.

Comment: @gunr2171 no, because I need to know whether or not they actually sent the message.

Comment: @gunr2171 fair point.

Comment: So did Microsoft make no more "Interops" that work with their products after 2013? Because for the life of me I can't find such a library/PIA, and the 2013 Interop is failing when I try to use it with 365.

Comment: I believe the Office tools installed with VS 2017+ all work with modern versions of Office, though I'm not sure if they're capable of doing what you're looking to do. I'd start with this [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=getting+started+with+office+365+c%23&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS922US922&oq=getting+started+with+office+365+c%23&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i22i29i30.11064j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), though I'm not sure how far it'll get you.

Comment: @WestleyBennett Well, it's either Office 365 or it's Office 2013, which one is it? VS 2013/2015 -> Office 2013. VS 2017 -> Office 2016. VS 2019 -> Office 2019/365

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have VS2019, and Office 365. I was trying to force my program to use the Outlook 2013 Interop to communicate with Outlook, but it failed (probably because it's the wrong version!) Hence my question... where the heck is the 365 Interop???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer for myself. I used VoidTools' app Everything to find the location of the latest version of the Outlook PIA:

[image: Everything App Outlook PIA Location]

And I manually added that as a COM assembly reference into my application. In my case, it was at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll". Then I had to do the following:

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = 
                (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application"));
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.Display(true);
```

And it's now working! I can work from here using the good old Outlook Interop that I'm used to, but it was a pain to figure out how to get it to work! I don't know why Microsoft seems to be "hiding" this Interop and any references to it from their websites!

Although my question has been downvoted for some reason, I'm not going to delete this, as someone else might come across this same issue. And I might need to refer to this again in the future if I forget. This DOES work on the Outlook 365 Desktop Application!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [Outlook VSTO Addin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019) which integrates back to your main application.  If it is in a controlled environment you add-in could be deployed to all users in the office.  If you need to you could also create an Outlook web add-in.